# Win32 alternative for the destructor in pthread_keycreate (when I cannot control dllmain)

Tags: multithreading, winapi

In pthreads, you can associate a destructor function with each per-thread storage slot. When a thread dies, if the slot is non-0, the destructor is called.

In a Win32 DLL, the DLLMain function, called at thread exit, can do the same thing.

What can I do in code that lives in a purely static library?

Comment: Which POSIX Threads for Win32 are you using?

Comment: @vy32 None. On Windows, I use the WIn32 API.

Comment: But I thought that pthread_* was part of POSIX threads and not WIN32 threads.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Windows support Thread Local Storage (TLS) in a DLL. It can be very practical if you want have some memory blocks **per thread** with the unique value (unique per thread). Inside of any other function from the DLL you can get the value which correspond to **the current thread** in very easy way. It is very useful in some scenarios. Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686997(VS.85).aspx) for more details.

I dun't use `pthreads` myself, but I suppose that per-thread storage slot introduced to make the work with TLS more comfortable.

**UPDATED**: From your comment I see that you misunderstand my answer. I'm not a POSIX developer, I develop in Win32 only and your question is about *WIn32 API possibilities* of per-thread allocation and deallocations. I try to explain the possibilities and you can decide yourself which one are better for your specific scenarios.

The equivalent of `pthread_XXX` functions in Win32 are following:

- [pthread_key_create](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_create.html)    [TlsAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686801(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [pthread_setspecific](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_setspecific.html)   [TlsSetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686818(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [pthread_getspecific](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_getspecific.html)   [TlsGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686812(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [pthread_key_delete](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_delete.html)    [TlsFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686804(v=VS.85).aspx)

I **not** recommended you to use the construct [__declspec(thread)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb.aspx), which is more compiler specific.

The example [Using Thread Local Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686991(v=VS.85).aspx) shows how to use [thread local storage (TLS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686749(v=VS.85).aspx) without DLLs, but I personally like and use TLS only in DLL.

The [destructor](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_create.html#tag_03_534_08_01) parameter of the [pthread_key_create](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_create.htm) function has no analog in Win32, but I don't see here any problem. All C/C++ compilers support `__try {/**/} __finally {/**/}` construct of the [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx) so you can use it in the body of your thread function and implement in the way any [Cleaning up Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stbzd0y4.aspx) exacly like you can do this in the main thread.

I find pity that you not included in your question an example which shows how you typically use [destructor](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_create.html#tag_03_534_08_01)  of the [pthread_key_create](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_create.htm) function. I find that examples can clear much things without a lot of words. So if my answer do not help you we can better explain all in examples: you write an example and probably short comment what it should do and I could write the same code using Win32 API only in C or C++.

Comment: The point of my question is the management of this in code that does NOT live in a DLL. The __declspec thing has nasty limitations.

Comment: OK, the SEH suggestion is in fact responsive to the question.

Comment: @bmargulies: SEH is one of my favorite construction and `__try {/**/} __finally {/**/}` is the oldest C language extension introduced in the time of the first version of Windows NT (NT 3.1). It makes the structure of the program very easy and permit to write robust code without the usage of smart pointers.

Comment: -1 , Even with the information provided, I didn't find your answer useful, given the question.

Comment: @self.: What information exactly you search for? The old question was about Win32 alternatives of memory managements per thread. One needed to made the allocations *not during DLL initialization*. Almost the only possibility which provides Win32 for the case are APIs `TlsAlloc`, `TlsSetValue`, `TlsGetValue` and `TlsFree`. One can use the APIs in EXE and not only in DLL. It was my answer 4 years ago. I suppose that you had *another* problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard problem, and requires sticking callbacks in special locations. Luckily for you, it is solved in [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread). Use `boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit`, or `boost::thread_specific_ptr`

Comment: OK, but what about everybody who's not using Boost?

Comment: With a modern compiler just declare your variable `static thread_local`

Comment: When is the destructor called for things declared `static thread_local`?

Comment: The destructor for a `thread_local` variable is called when the thread exits

Comment: So, this is a C++ only solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond Chen explains in his 2019 blog post [Fibers aren’t useful for much any more; there’s just one corner of it that remains useful for a reason unrelated to fibers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191011-00/?p=102989), the best solution to this problem is to use fiber-local storage (FLS) instead of thread-local storage (TLS); unlike `TlsAlloc`, `FlsAlloc` has a destructor callback; otherwise the APIs are interchangeable.

This would be a change in behaviour if your application uses fibers, but very few applications do – doing so is no longer recommended since the problems fibers cause in practice outweigh their theoretical benefits. For an application which doesn't use fibers, FLS behaves identically to TLS, except for TLS lacking this useful destructor callback.